# react-navigation undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0 _reactnavigation.StackNavigator)')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a new project. Then I'm installing the react-navigation but it's not working.

**Code** :

```
import { StackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation';
import Intro from './src/pages/Intro';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Intro: {
    screen: Intro,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Intro",
      header: null,
      navigationBar: null
    },
  },
});
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

**Error** :

[image]

========================================

Comment: Hi Yunus. Can you post your App.js file. I am also getting same error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This helped me after a lot of searching.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983086/undefined-is-not-a-function-near-reactnavigation-stacknavigator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm considering that you installed react-navigation correctly.

```
npm install --save react-navigation
```

Try this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Intro from './src/pages/Intro';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Intro: {
    screen: Intro,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "Intro",
      header: null,
      navigationBar: null
    },
  },
});
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. I get undefined in not object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State' error now.

Comment: did you installed react-native, expo-cli correctly?

Comment: export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator />
    );
  }
}
change to

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
Now work.

Comment: undefined in not object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State' error now.  I am also getting same error

Answer (score 2):

I have given it up half a month ago.

However, today it worked without any change, without any dependency refresh!

So, I think maybe it need a **computer reboot**. WTF.

Answer (score 1):

Installed navigation:

```
npm install --save react-navigation
npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
react-native link
```

Try this `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './screens/Home';
import Settings from './screens/Settings';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { 
    screen: Home,
  },
  SettingScreen: { 
    screen: Settings, 
  },
});

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `react-native`, `react`, `react-navigation` versions are as follows:

```
 "react-navigation": "^2.18.2",

 "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",

 "react-native": "0.57.4",
```

Hope this helps you. Because the latest version of `v3.0` has more issues in navigation.

Comment: export default class App extends Component { render() { return ( <AppNavigator /> ); } } change to const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator); export default AppContainer; Now work. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Yunus. Can you post your App.js file. I am also getting same error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% working.

Use of react-navigation (3.x) version ^3.0.0:

```
import {
    createDrawerNavigator,
    createStackNavigator,
    createBottomTabNavigator,
    createAppContainer,
} from 'react-navigation';


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```