# My splash screen won't move on to the next screen on react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, splash-screen, react-native-ios, stack-navigator

I am new at react native and I am trying to create an iOS app. My splash screen works fine and loads the initial App.js screen when creating project fine. However, when I change the return to my own .js file, it fails to build and is stuck on splash screen. Please give me some tips, I followed many tutorials.

App.js

```
// App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';

import GetStarted from './authentication/GetStarted'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'

const AuthNav = createAppContainer(
  createStackNavigator({
    GetStarted: { screen: GetStarted },
  })
);

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {

  componentDidMount() {
    SplashScreen.hide()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthNav />
    );
  }
}
```

GetStarted.js

```
//GetStarted.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';

export default class GetStarted extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Lets get started</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItem: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  }
});
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "TestApp",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
},
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.3",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.0.0",
    "jest": "24.0.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
},
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `change the return to my own .js `? Please elaborate more.

Comment: Please upload your `package.json` and/or any errors you are receiving in console.

Comment: @10101010 Like in App.js, in the return block, I replaced the original View and Text tags with <AuthStack/> and tried to make the screen after the splash screen my GetStarted.js

Comment: @ChrisPoe I added my package.json

Comment: The splash screen is covering the error. Disable the splash screen from showing in the native code. Rebuild the app and you should see the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `"react-navigation": "^3.3.0"` and trying to import `StackNavigator`. In `v2+` they renamed `StackNavigator` to `createStackNavigator`. Looks like the tutorial you used is using `v1`. So, you can either change the version you are using to `"react-navigation": "^1.5.2"` or stay and use `createStackNavigator`. If you choose to stick with the version you are on (`v2+`), read another one of my responses to this same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53983086/undefined-is-not-a-function-near-reactnavigation-stacknavigator/53983329#53983329); it will explain further.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I looked at your other post's answer and I followed it but it is still not working. I updated the code above.

Comment: Is this an Expo project or plain React Native? @squirreldev

Comment: This is a plain React Native @ChrisPoe

Comment: The only other thing I see that it could be is `react-native-splash-screen`. After installing it did you link it using `react-native link react-native-splash-screen`? Without me knowing what the error is, it is hard to debug @squirreldev

Comment: yes; I followed the steps from https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae @ChrisPoe

Comment: Like I said, I'd need some kind of error to go off of at this point. The react navigation versioning was definitely a problem, I know that. If it's all the same to you I'd recommend using Expo. They have a great `AppLoading` api for handling splash screens. @squirreldev

Comment: Yes, I believe you are probably right about the splash screen. So I removed the splash screen and now it's showing my error. It says "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RootComponent.prototype')

Comment: @squirreldev that's usually an import error. Here's a sandbox where I removed `SplashScreen` and the app loads as expected https://snack.expo.io/@chris-bytelion/ZXhjaX

Comment: Thank you for following up and helping! I don’t know why but today the app loaded without the error from yesterday. I think it was after I restarted my laptop. @ChrisPoe

Comment: Glad to hear! @squirreldev